# How do I export a certificate as .pem?

Tags: ssl, certificate, pem

How can I export a certificate as a `.pem` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following link is has a code snippet to export a certificate to a PEM format string:

[Exporting a Certificate as BASE-64 encoded .cer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739407/exporting-a-certificate-as-base-64-encoded-cer)

Please have a look.

Comment: This is OPENSSL? - How to use openssl in c++?

Comment: X509certificate is a .Net class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.aspx

Comment: If you want to use openSSL is C++, check if this link helps
https://thunked.org/programming/openssl-tutorial-client-t11.html

Comment: Can you complete my project?