# Get certificates information using powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl, powershell-core

My idea is to have a powershell code that is available for both (windows and ubuntu) with few changes (like the path in get-childitem),so I tried the following script on ubuntu , but did not work on windows and it shows me the following error

> openssl.exe : Can't open [Subject]
>
> At line:5 char:10
>
> - $var = ((& C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe x509 -in $File -dates -no ...

Here is the code that I've wrote:

```
$files = get-childitem Cert:\LocalMachine\My    
foreach ($File in $files) 
{ 
$var = ((& C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe x509 -in $File -dates -noout) - 
match 'notAfter')
Write-Host $var
}
```

Another remark: what syntaxe to use with openssl to get certificate name

Comment: Use the same code, but differentiate the platform with the automatic variables `$IsWindows`,`$IsLinux`,`$IsMacOs`. I.e. `if ($IsLinux){"Do Liux stuff"} elseif ($IsMacOS) {"Do OS X stuff"} else {"Do Windws stuff"}`

Answer (score 2):

`openssl x509 -in` expects a file path as it's argument, not the custom formatted output of a `[X509Certificate]` object.

What you can do instead is [re-encode the certificate in PEM format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739407/exporting-a-certificate-as-base-64-encoded-cer) (base64) and pipe that to `openssl`:

```
if($IsWindows){
    foreach($cert in Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My\) {
       # Write BEGIN line
       $certStrings  = @('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----')

       # Export cert data
       $certData     = $cert.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Cert)

       # Convert to Base64 + append
       $certStrings += [Convert]::ToBase64String($certData, [System.Base64FormattingOptions]::InsertLineBreaks)

       # Write END line
       $certStrings += '-----END CERTIFICATE-----'

       # Pass off to openssl.exe
       $NotAfter = @(($certStrings -join [System.Environment]::NewLine) | .\path\to\openssl.exe x509 -text -noout -dates) -match 'notAfter'

       Write-Host $NotAfter
    }
}
else {
    foreach($cert in Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My\) {
        $notAfter = @(& path\to\openssl.exe x509 -in $cert -dates -noout) -match 'notAfter'
Write-Host $notAfter
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. The encoding to base 64 conversion is fabulous

Comment: I tried it on ubuntu and it did not work, it told me "Method invocation failed cause it does not containe the methode Export"

Comment: As @LotPings pointed out you can attempt to detect the platform with the `$Is*` automatic variables, updated answer